# How we get global x,y position,when we are clicking in a datagrid cell

Tags: apache-flex

How we get global x,y position,when we are clicking in a datagrid cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the `MouseEvent`

```
//i.e., if you are inside the clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
trace(e.stageX + ", " + e.stageY)
```

Otherwise:

```
var obj:DisplayObject = theDesiredObject;
var globalPoint:Point = obj.localToGlobal(new Point(obj.mouseX, obj.mouseY));
trace(globalPoint.x + ", " + globalPoint.y);
```