# How to get a (x,y) position pointing with mouse in a interactive plot (Python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, widget

I use ipython notebook (with the magic `%matplotlib nbagg`). I was reviewing the `matplotlib.widget.Cursor` but the cursor is only viewed [widgets.Cursor](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.3/examples/widgets/cursor.html). So I'd like to select two points clicking in the plot and get the initial and final x,y-position (e.g. time vs Temperature, selecting to points must return initial and final time). I need it for selecting manually an arbitrary interval. I think it's similar to [get global x,y position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183698/how-we-get-global-x-y-position-when-we-are-clicking-in-a-datagrid-cell), but I didn't understand well in that post.

How can I get a (x,y) position pointing with mouse in a interactive plot (Python)?

Obs. Something similar to CURSOR Procedure in IDL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) should work.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

f,a = plt.subplots()
x = np.linspace(1,10,100)
y = np.sin(x)
a.plot(x,y)
pos = []
def onclick(event):
    pos.append([event.xdata,event.ydata])
f.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
f.show()
```

On each click the current cursor position is appended to pos.