# Get X,Y Position in Figure (not in Plot)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question about the X and Y Position in figures. How you can see I am working with gridspec for a better layout and adding Text to a figure. The problem is that I am trying to get the exact Position manually. Which means I am changing the X and Y in `fig.text(0.2, 0.5, 'matplotlib')`  until I get the final figure.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

vector = np.arange(0,100)
time = np.arange(0,vector.shape[0])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)
    
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :])        
ax1.plot(time,vector)  
fig.text(0.2, 0.5, 'matplotlib')
```

At [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379502/how-get-a-x-y-position-pointing-with-mouse-in-a-interactive-plot-python) I already found an interactive solution but its only working for the Plot.

Does someone have an idea how to manage this?

Comment: Of which item do you want to get the exact position?

Comment: I want to find out the position of the blue sqaure depending to the total figure. So i dont need to change it hundred times until i find it out.

Comment: Is there anything in the blue square? If yes: It is possible to find the position. If no: It is not possible, since a non-existing object has no existing position.

Comment: No. 'matplotlib' needs to get there. Its the final position of 'matplotlib' until i try it out with changen X and Y. A solution like in the Link where you can get X and Y with the mouse will be nice. But I am not able to code it :S

Comment: @Scotty1- ah ok. How can I get the X,Y Position of the figure (all corner)? Maybe I am able to make a workaround :)

Comment: The x,y position in the figure is in the (0, 1) range relative to the figure size. So `fig.text(0.2, 0.5, 'matplotlib') ` means that you position your text at 20% of the figure width from the left size and at 50% of the fig height from the bottom. Knowing this, it should be easy to set the position, f.i. `fig.text(0.75, 0.3, 'matplotlib')` looks quite close to what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [blended transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations), where the y-coordinates have a [figure transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html). And the x-coordinates have a [axes transform](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates). The figure transform is measured 0 at the left/bottom and 1 at the right/top of the figure. The axes transform is similar, but regarding the axes. The parameter `clip_on=False` allows to draw outside the axes region (text allows this by default).

```py
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(gridspec_kw={})

# the x coords of this transformation are axes, and the y coord are fig
trans = mtransforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transAxes, fig.transFigure)

x, w = 1, -0.3  # axes coordinates
y, h = 0.04, 0.06  # figure coordinates
ax.text(x + w / 2, y + h / 2, 'hello', transform=trans, ha='center', va='center')
rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x, y), w, h, transform=trans, edgecolor='crimson', facecolor='yellow', clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(rect)

fig.tight_layout(pad=2)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: You can set the vertical alignment `va='right'` to have the right margin of the text align with the right axis.  You can also use `transform=ax.transAxes` with negative y-coordinates to plot everything relative to the axes.